# HTML CSS clear both issue

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

How can we have image in new line and h2 in other line keeping all style in h2 
we can see  that both image and h2 are float together
we want to have both in different line 
please give proper clarification so all other programmer also refer and use in there code 
question is very simple have to use float and clear property but dont know where perfectly so please check it and reply as soon as possible
we have seen such issue many times

```css
#back-to-top {
  position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
}
h1, h2
{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;}
h1{
   text-align: center;
}
h2{display:inline-block;
clear: both;}
img{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang= "en">
<head>
  <meta charset= "UTF-8">
  <title>Recipe project - Module 1</title>
  </head>
  
<body>
  <h1 id = "top">My favorite Recipes: </h1>
  
 <nav> 
   <ul>
     <li><a href=#first>Panipuri</a></li>
     <li><a href=#second>Handvo</a></li>
     <li><a href=#third>Dosa</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
  
  <article>
    <h2 id="first">Panipuri</h2>
 <img src= "https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-14f6bc4a3b89ae33a33107a9b56b38e7" alt="delicious pani puri plate" width= 350 title="once you have it you will forget all the items">
  <br>
   <br>
    <span><strong>List of Ingredients:</strong></span>
    <ul>
      <li>Kothamir Pani</li>
    <li>Dates Pani</li>
    <li>Puri</li>
    <li>Masala Ragda</li>
    </ul>
      
      <q>Have it and forget everthing</q> 
  <p><strong>Steps:</strong></p>
  <ol>
    <li>Make Masal Ragda</li>
    <li>make Kothmir pani</li>
    <li>make Dates pani</li>
    <li>take Puri and start eating</li>
    </ol></article>
    <br>
      <article>
<h2 id="second">Handvo</h2>
<img src="http://somethingscookingwithalpa.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/handvo-WEB.jpg" alt = "handvo plate" width=350 title="handvo really teasty have it">
      <br>
      <br>
      <span><strong>List of Ingredients:</strong></span>
    <ul>
      <li>1 cup rice</li>
    <li>1 cup yellow moong dal</li>
    <li>3 cups buttermilk</li>
    <li>3-4 green chillies finely chopped</li>
    <li>3 Tbsp coriander chopped</li>
      
    </ul>
       <p> Follow the step  to have <q> A traditional Gujarati savoury cake. It is made with a combinations of lentils, rice and buttermilk</q></p>
  <p><strong>Steps:</strong></p>
  <ol>
    <li>Take butter milk Add salt, soda and flour, mix well,Keep it aside for 6-7 hours.</li>
    <li>Grate bottle gourd and squeeze out excess water,add gourd,coriander,green chillies</li>
    <li>Heat oil in a pan,urad & channa dals and seeds,Allow to splutter,pouin the batter and mix it thoroughly.</li>
    <li>Check by inserting a skewer,which should come out clean. Slice into wedges and serve hot.</li>
    </ol>
        </article>
      
  <article>
<h2 id="third">Dosa</h2>
    <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/oRMz04HKckdj5s4aPAImXQHJ1d0=/0x0:2808x1872/1200x800/filters:focal(1180x712:1628x1160)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/56417501/Dosa2.1504026967.jpg" alt= "dosa in plate for dinner with chatni" width=350>
        <br>
        <br>
         <span><strong>List of Ingredients:</strong></span>
    <ul>
      <li>3/4 cup Parboiled and 3/4 cup Regular Rice</li>
    <li>1/2 cup Urad Dal and 1/2 tablespoon Chana Dal</li>
    <li>1/4 teaspoon Fenugreek Seeds (methi dana)</li>
    <li>Water as needed ,Salt to taste,Oil for shallow frying</li>
    <li>3 Tbsp coriander chopped</li>
    </ul>
<p> try it  <q> All you need is love. But a little dosa doesn’t hurt.</q></p>
  <p><strong>Steps:</strong></p>
  <ol>
    <li> The batter should be fluffy and not very thick. Transfer it to a large container</li>
    <li> Take all the ingredients to prepare the dosa batter. Rice, urad dal and fenugreek seeds are the main ingredients.</li>
    <li> Apply 1-teaspoon oil around the edges of dosa .</li>
    <li> Cook until the bottom surface turns light brown and the edges start to come upward.
</li>
    </ol>
           </article>
      
        
        
        
 <a href=#top > <img id="back-to-top" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKESsqyheQZhgMM0UMtRe39dEkePwmEL0TPgTwMnpFTZfSLxJh" alt= "back to top image" width=30></a>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Either you can set  `display: block;` to the image or to the heading h2.

Comment: remove `h2{display:inline-block;` from h2 than it's working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you just want to change

```
h2{display:inline-block;
clear: both;}
img{
  clear:both;
}
```

to

```
img{
  display:block;
}
```

and remove those `<br>` tags instead?

Comment: Similar to my answer, but you added `img{display:block;}`. That's not required for this code, but it can be used instead of adding `<br><br>` after each image like the OP did.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any `float` property in your CSS. `clear: both` only works with `float`. The issue you have is because of the `display:inline-block;` set on the `h2`, so delete it and everything should work properly. You don't need the `clear: both`:

```css
#back-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

h1,
h2 {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Recipe project - Module 1</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="top">My favorite Recipes: </h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href=#first>Panipuri</a></li>
      <li><a href=#second>Handvo</a></li>
      <li><a href=#third>Dosa</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <article>
    <h2 id="first">Panipuri</h2>
 <img src= "https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-14f6bc4a3b89ae33a33107a9b56b38e7" alt="delicious pani puri plate" width= 350 title="once you have it you will forget all the items">
    <br>
    <br>
    <span><strong>List of Ingredients:</strong></span>
    <ul>
      <li>Kothamir Pani</li>
      <li>Dates Pani</li>
      <li>Puri</li>
      <li>Masala Ragda</li>
    </ul>
    <q>Have it and forget everthing</q>
    <p><strong>Steps:</strong></p>
    <ol>
      <li>Make Masal Ragda</li>
      <li>make Kothmir pani</li>
      <li>make Dates pani</li>
      <li>take Puri and start eating</li>
    </ol>
  </article>
  <br>
  <article>
    <h2 id="second">Handvo</h2>
    <img src="http://somethingscookingwithalpa.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/handvo-WEB.jpg" alt="handvo plate" width=350 title="handvo really teasty have it">
    <br>
    <br>
    <span><strong>List of Ingredients:</strong></span>
    <ul>
      <li>1 cup rice</li>
      <li>1 cup yellow moong dal</li>
      <li>3 cups buttermilk</li>
      <li>3-4 green chillies finely chopped</li>
      <li>3 Tbsp coriander chopped</li>
    </ul>
    <p> Follow the step to have <q> A traditional Gujarati savoury cake. It is made with a combinations of lentils, rice and buttermilk</q></p>
    <p><strong>Steps:</strong></p>
    <ol>
      <li>Take butter milk Add salt, soda and flour, mix well,Keep it aside for 6-7 hours.</li>
      <li>Grate bottle gourd and squeeze out excess water,add gourd,coriander,green chillies</li>
      <li>Heat oil in a pan,urad & channa dals and seeds,Allow to splutter,pouin the batter and mix it thoroughly.</li>
      <li>Check by inserting a skewer,which should come out clean. Slice into wedges and serve hot.</li>
    </ol>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2 id="third">Dosa</h2>
    <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/oRMz04HKckdj5s4aPAImXQHJ1d0=/0x0:2808x1872/1200x800/filters:focal(1180x712:1628x1160)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/56417501/Dosa2.1504026967.jpg" alt="dosa in plate for dinner with chatni" width=350>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span><strong>List of Ingredients:</strong></span>
    <ul>
      <li>3/4 cup Parboiled and 3/4 cup Regular Rice</li>
      <li>1/2 cup Urad Dal and 1/2 tablespoon Chana Dal</li>
      <li>1/4 teaspoon Fenugreek Seeds (methi dana)</li>
      <li>Water as needed ,Salt to taste,Oil for shallow frying</li>
      <li>3 Tbsp coriander chopped</li>
    </ul>
    <p> try it <q> All you need is love. But a little dosa doesn’t hurt.</q></p>
    <p><strong>Steps:</strong></p>
    <ol>
      <li> The batter should be fluffy and not very thick. Transfer it to a large container</li>
      <li> Take all the ingredients to prepare the dosa batter. Rice, urad dal and fenugreek seeds are the main ingredients.</li>
      <li> Apply 1-teaspoon oil around the edges of dosa .</li>
      <li> Cook until the bottom surface turns light brown and the edges start to come upward.
      </li>
    </ol>
  </article>
  <a href=#top> <img id="back-to-top" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKESsqyheQZhgMM0UMtRe39dEkePwmEL0TPgTwMnpFTZfSLxJh" alt="back to top image" width=30></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i want ot keep the h2 to inline-block sir

Answer (score 1):

add `width: 100%;` to `h2` tag

```css
#back-to-top {
  position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
}
h1, h2
{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;}
h1{
   text-align: center;
}
h2{display:inline-block;
clear: both;
width: 100%;}
img{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang= "en">
<head>
  <meta charset= "UTF-8">
  <title>Recipe project - Module 1</title>
  </head>
  
<body>
  <h1 id = "top">My favorite Recipes: </h1>
  
 <nav> 
   <ul>
     <li><a href=#first>Panipuri</a></li>
     <li><a href=#second>Handvo</a></li>
     <li><a href=#third>Dosa</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
  
  <article>
    <h2 id="first">Panipuri</h2>
 <img src= "https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-14f6bc4a3b89ae33a33107a9b56b38e7" alt="delicious pani puri plate" width= 350 title="once you have it you will forget all the items">
  <br>
   <br>
    <span><strong>List of Ingredients:</strong></span>
    <ul>
      <li>Kothamir Pani</li>
    <li>Dates Pani</li>
    <li>Puri</li>
    <li>Masala Ragda</li>
    </ul>
      
      <q>Have it and forget everthing</q> 
  <p><strong>Steps:</strong></p>
  <ol>
    <li>Make Masal Ragda</li>
    <li>make Kothmir pani</li>
    <li>make Dates pani</li>
    <li>take Puri and start eating</li>
    </ol></article>
    <br>
      <article>
<h2 id="second">Handvo</h2>
<img src="http://somethingscookingwithalpa.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/handvo-WEB.jpg" alt = "handvo plate" width=350 title="handvo really teasty have it">
      <br>
      <br>
      <span><strong>List of Ingredients:</strong></span>
    <ul>
      <li>1 cup rice</li>
    <li>1 cup yellow moong dal</li>
    <li>3 cups buttermilk</li>
    <li>3-4 green chillies finely chopped</li>
    <li>3 Tbsp coriander chopped</li>
      
    </ul>
       <p> Follow the step  to have <q> A traditional Gujarati savoury cake. It is made with a combinations of lentils, rice and buttermilk</q></p>
  <p><strong>Steps:</strong></p>
  <ol>
    <li>Take butter milk Add salt, soda and flour, mix well,Keep it aside for 6-7 hours.</li>
    <li>Grate bottle gourd and squeeze out excess water,add gourd,coriander,green chillies</li>
    <li>Heat oil in a pan,urad & channa dals and seeds,Allow to splutter,pouin the batter and mix it thoroughly.</li>
    <li>Check by inserting a skewer,which should come out clean. Slice into wedges and serve hot.</li>
    </ol>
        </article>
      
  <article>
<h2 id="third">Dosa</h2>
    <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/oRMz04HKckdj5s4aPAImXQHJ1d0=/0x0:2808x1872/1200x800/filters:focal(1180x712:1628x1160)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/56417501/Dosa2.1504026967.jpg" alt= "dosa in plate for dinner with chatni" width=350>
        <br>
        <br>
         <span><strong>List of Ingredients:</strong></span>
    <ul>
      <li>3/4 cup Parboiled and 3/4 cup Regular Rice</li>
    <li>1/2 cup Urad Dal and 1/2 tablespoon Chana Dal</li>
    <li>1/4 teaspoon Fenugreek Seeds (methi dana)</li>
    <li>Water as needed ,Salt to taste,Oil for shallow frying</li>
    <li>3 Tbsp coriander chopped</li>
    </ul>
<p> try it  <q> All you need is love. But a little dosa doesn’t hurt.</q></p>
  <p><strong>Steps:</strong></p>
  <ol>
    <li> The batter should be fluffy and not very thick. Transfer it to a large container</li>
    <li> Take all the ingredients to prepare the dosa batter. Rice, urad dal and fenugreek seeds are the main ingredients.</li>
    <li> Apply 1-teaspoon oil around the edges of dosa .</li>
    <li> Cook until the bottom surface turns light brown and the edges start to come upward.
</li>
    </ol>
           </article>
      
        
        
        
 <a href=#top > <img id="back-to-top" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKESsqyheQZhgMM0UMtRe39dEkePwmEL0TPgTwMnpFTZfSLxJh" alt= "back to top image" width=30></a>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but than it will block whole area and style will go to whole area
its done we have to make image as display block